# FFMPEG Recode all audio streams while keeping originals

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-streaming, audio-processing

I am trying to add a additional set of audio tracks into some video files, as part of a automated process. I would like to keep all the original audio tracks and have a second re-coded copy.

What I have been using is:

```
ffmpeg -i file
-map 0:v -codec:v copy
-map 0:a -codec:a copy
-map 0:a:0 -codec:a:0 aac -strict experimental ...(Bitrate, filters etc all with :a:0)
-map 0:s -codec:s copy
output file
```

However I can't work out how to change this to handle input files that have multiple audio tracks as it will only convert the first.

If I change the :a:0 to :a on the codec line it produces the extra copy I need but overrides the copy codec for the original copy.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways to do this.

First uses a single command but can get long. Idea is to conditionally map audio streams upto the maximum possible streams a file may have. Not elegant but will get the job done.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4
          -c copy
          -map 0:v
          -map 0:a:0? -c:a:0 copy
          -map 0:a:0? -c:a:1 aac
          -map 0:a:1? -c:a:2 copy
          -map 0:a:1? -c:a:3 aac
          -map 0:a:2? -c:a:4 copy
          -map 0:a:2? -c:a:5 aac
          -map 0:a:3? -c:a:6 copy
          -map 0:a:3? -c:a:7 aac
out.mp4
```

Second method transcodes all audio tracks and pipes it to another ffmpeg execution for copying. With this method, you have less flexibility with stream order in the final output.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:a aac -map 0:a -f nut - |
  ffmpeg -i - -i in.mp4 -c copy -map 1 -map 0 out.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen the conditional mapping [link](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Advanced-options) (for anyone else looking)I think the piping output may be the nicer but I don't think it would work with my automated setup.